# QField problem - visualization of the construction line

Tags: qgis, qfield

During the editing of a linear shp with the QField application, a construction line of red color and of small thickness is visualized (in the passage from a beaten point to the next point).

Is it possible to change the thickness and color of the construction line?

Is this a decision to be made in the QGIS project or in the QField app?

Using QField outdoors and keeping a satellite image or google satellite service as a background map, the construction line is hardly visible.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't change the digitising line properties in QField (you can do it in QGIS but those settings are for QGIS only and don't get carried over to QField). I would recommend putting in a feature request on github. The devs are quite responsive.